# Strange Binding Behavior in $onInit

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to access data from a binding ("months"):

```
.component('component', {
    bindings: {
        months: '<',
    },
    templateUrl: 'url',
    controller: 'controller'
})

.controller('controller', function() {

    var vm = this;

    this.$onInit = function() {
        console.log(vm.months, vm.months.length, vm.months instanceof Array);
        vm.months.forEach(function(month) {
            console.log(month);
        });
    };
});
```

That first console.log statement prints out some strange output:

[image: screenshot of developer tools console output]

The data is there (an array with 12 items), but the length is zero(?!). This I don't understand, at all.

When I attempt to iterate through the array, that may or may not exist, each month is not printed out in the console (see inner body of forEach loop). I can't for the life of me figure out why this is the case. What am I missing here?

Comment: Does something push data into `months` at some point? Keep in mind, `console.log` shows live data for objects / arrays

Comment: @Phil data does get pushed, before (at least I'm fairly certain) the data is passed to the binding. Either way, I'm printing out the array and its length in the same console.log statement, why those two things would be different while in the same line of code is what confuses me here.

Comment: Because as I said, the `console.log` output is live for objects and arrays. The array length is a primitive value (integer) and is thus, not updated in the console output when the data changes. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(vm.months))`